# How to use quill emoji with ng quill

Tags: javascript, angular, quill

I would like use quill emoji with ng quill
to transform automatically text to smileys (like facebook or asana) :) :( :'( <3 and more

I tried to install it but it seems doesn't work

can you tell me the right way to do that with angular js quill ?

thanks, in advance

Comment: i seen it, but it doesnt help @mplungjan

Comment: It tells you it likely does not work. Last message was in March

Answer (score 1):

Hi first of all you have to add styles of emoji in angular.json to styles arrary
``

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
    "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
    "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
    "node_modules/quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css",
    "node_modules/q`enter code here`uill-mention/dist/quill.mention.min.css"
],
```

and then in your component at the top you should import this line of code

`import 'quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.js';`

if you'll import in `angular.json` you'll get errors because emoji plugin needs bellow modules, and you have access to them if you import js file here in component 

  `"emoji-toolbar": true,
  "emoji-shortname": true,
  "emoji-textarea": true`

and then create a config variable

```
  const config = {
      'emoji-toolbar': true,
      'emoji-textarea': true,
      'emoji-shortname': true,
      toolbar: {
        container: [
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'], // toggled buttons
          ['code-block'],
          // [{header: 1}, {header: 2}], // custom button values
          [{list: 'ordered'}, {list: 'bullet'}],
          // [{'script': 'sub'}, {'script': 'super'}],      // superscript/subscript
          [{indent: '-1'}, {indent: '+1'}], // outdent/indent
          [{direction: 'rtl'}], // text direction
          [{size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}], // custom dropdown
          [{header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false]}],
          ['image'],                                    // image
          ['code-block'], // code block
          [{align: []}],
          ['emoji'],
          ['clean'], // remove formatting button
          ['link', 'image', 'video']['emoji']
        ]
      }
    };
```

after that you can pass to your angular quill-editor

```
 <quill-editor theme="bubble"
    [placeholder]="editorPlacehorder"
    [modules]="moduleConfig"
    [(ngModel)]="feedPost.content">
```

This works 100%, so if you have any questions fell free to ask

Comment: Hello! I followed all of your steps but what i get is a button with this class --> .ql-emoji, but it's invisible (even though the cursor is pointer) and nothing happens when i click it. I imported the css of the emoji lib, config it with: toolbar: {
      container: [
        ..., ['emoji'] ],
      handlers: {'emoji': function() {}},
      'emoji-toolbar': true,
      'emoji-textarea': true,
      'emoji-shortname': true,
....
imported the library import 'quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.js'; in the component i'm creating the config. Can you help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that you can follow for getting quill-emoji to work using [ng-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ng-quill).

https://github.com/contentco/quill-emoji/blob/master/demo/angular.html

In a nutshell, you can just include quill-emoji after ng-quill in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.1/quill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng-quill.js"></script>
<script src="quill-emoji.js"></script>
```

In your angularjs code you can then just add it to the list of modules:

```
angular.module('quillTest', ['ngQuill']).controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', AppCtrl]);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Quill works'
  $scope.customModules = {
  toolbar: [
    ['emoji'],
  ],
  "emoji-toolbar": true,
  "emoji-shortname": true,
  "emoji-textarea": true
  }
 }
```

Back to your html then you can add:

```
<ng-quill-editor ng-model="title" modules="customModules"></ng-quill-editor>
```